# Reading input files and writing into output files - Python

Tags: python, input, output

I have an input file (input.txt) with the following information:

- Number of students (first line)
- Number of test scores (second line)
- list of student names and scores

So the text file looks something like this

```
4
5

Jane Doe,80,75,90,100,95,68
Sara Jones,65,80,72,90,75,80
Bill Smith,50,70,90,70,55,90
John Foles,95,90,85,80,88
```

I am trying to create a python program that will read this information, and output certain values (class average score, student names, student scores, etc) into a different file (output.txt).

I've been working through it, and I can never get my program to do everything that I need.  I am only able to, for example, output the class average only, or one student's score only.  I can't figure out how to output more than one function.

I could really use some help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Can you give us some code of yours, and explain the problem you want to solve. This post is too large to be answered without further information !

Comment: What is 4 and 5 in 1st and 2nd lines? Can you be more specific about your problem statement?

Comment: The idea is that the input.txt file can be altered.  The first like always refers to the number of students.  In this case, 4 students were used.  The second like is the number of test scores associated with each student.  My example is 5 test scores per student.

Comment: I get that my problem isn't all that clear, sorry about that.  Really, my issue is that I can understand each individual piece of this problem, but I have no idea how to combine it all.  I understand how to calculate score averages, I understand how to read an external input file, I understand how to write onto an external output file.  What I don't understand is how to combine it all.

Comment: @Calvin Does my answer help you? If so please accept it as the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use [Pandas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_introduction.htm) (See also [Pandas Manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)) for this.

First, copy the following to your clipboard:

```
Jane Doe,80,75,90,100,95,68
Sara Jones,65,80,72,90,75,80
Bill Smith,50,70,90,70,55,90
John Foles,95,90,85,80,88
```

Next, run the following script:

```
#%% Load Your Data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = ',')

# YOU WILL HAVE TO LOAD YOUR ACTUAL DATA AS FOLLOWS:
# file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt'
# df = pd.read_csv() 

number_of_students = df.shape[0]
number_of_tests = df.shape[1] -1  # This is the number of columns you have
score_names = ['score' + str(number+1) for number in range(number_of_tests)]
df.columns = ['student'] + score_names # Prepares the column names
df.set_index('student',inplace=True) # Makes the student names the index

#%% Calculate Maximum, Minimum and Average Class Score per test    
score_summaries = df.describe()

#%% Calulate the average score for all students across all tests
average_exam_score = df.mean().mean()

#%% A single students' score
df.loc['Sara Jones']
```

The script will calculate a couple of your requests. One thing it doesn't do is load your your file (you'll have to remove the lines containing the number of students & test scores but no worries, it is recalculated from the score data itself). I've included a hint about how to do this in the comments and leave it to you to implement.

I encourage you to go through it and explore what removing some lines or changing others will do.

Finally, on behalf of the SO community I say WELCOME! I know it seems like you're off to a rough start (with all the downvotes and all) but **don't let that discourage you**. Read through [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), come on back, and help us learn together!